# Angular 2: getting data from a Class

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

I've created a class for the default settings of my app. But I have no idea how to get the data from that class and use it in my html. I tried an observable but that's not really working.

My class looks like this:

```
export class Instellingen {
  urenTotBehandeling: number = 4;
  toonNaam: boolean = true;
  toonTijd: boolean = true;
  toonType: boolean = true;
  toonSanitair: boolean = true;
  toonKinder: boolean = true;
  toonSalon: boolean = true;
  toonKamerNummer: boolean = true;
  uren = [
    {value: 1, label: '1 uur'},
    {value: 2, label: '2 uren'},
    {value: 3, label: '3 uren'},
    {value: 4, label: '4 uren'}         ];
  hulpKleur:string= "red";
  behandelKleur:string = "orange";
  volKleur:string="green";
  leegKleur:string="white";    }
```

Comment: e.g.

export class OtherClass {
    constructor(){
        let a = new Instellingen();
        a.toonKamerNummer;
    }
}

Comment: I don't want to export it to another class. I want to use it in my html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an example how you can use it :

```
let i: Instellingen=new Instellingen();
console.log(i.urenTotBehandeling); // 4
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you but i'm trying to create a service or something so I can easely use it in my html :)

Comment: @KlaartjeDeBacker
you can create a variable that u can use it directly in html without creating class : 

`let Instellingen ={
 "urenTotBehandeling": 4,
 "toonNaam":true,
 "toonTijd": = true,
   //...
   "uren" : [
    {value: 1, label: '1 uur'},
    {value: 2, label: '2 uren'},
    {value: 3, label: '3 uren'},
    {value: 4, label: '4 uren'}  ],
  //..
}`

in ur html : 

  `<span> {{Instellingen.urenTotBehandeling}} </span>`

Comment: I tried this approach but when I type {{Instellingen.urenBehandeling}} I get  Cannot read property 'urenBehandeling' of undefined

Comment: have you defined `Instellingen` in your typescript file? can you show me a part of your code ?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to solve it by just typing in {{urenTotBehandeling}}

Answer (score 4):

The best approach to get the default settings from a class in application will be:

1. Create a service and add it to the **Provider** in your AppModule/module
2. Import that service and inject it in your component's constructor
3. Use it in your code.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to create a service for this. But I'm having issues with how to do it exactly. I can fetch data from a json file with a service, and this is probably easier so I feel a bit silly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'    
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'    
@Component({
selector :'ang-model',
template :`
Model :<input [(ngModel)] ='name' /> // Data Binding 
       {{name }} // string interpolation`
})
export class AngModelComponent{
       name : string = "Practice ";
}
```

Try the above approach of data binding and string interpolation